# Unable to compare dates when using ActiveRecord::Validator classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with this restriction! I can't compare two dates and the console gives me this error:

```
undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the code I wrote so far.

```
# app/models/reservation.rb

class CountValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if (record.second || record.first)
      record.errors[:base]<< ' error '
    end 
  end 
end

class DepartureValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if (record.date_trip < Date.today)
      record.errors[:base]<< ' error '
    end 
  end 
end 

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with DepartureValidator
  validates_with CountValidator
  belongs_to :dep ,:class_name => 'Stop', :foreign_key => 'dep_id'
  belongs_to :arr ,:class_name => 'Stop',:foreign_key => 'arr_id'
  belongs_to :route
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :CountStop, :to => :route, prefix: true, :allow_nil => false
  delegate :city ,:to => :arr, :allow_nil => false
  delegate :city ,:to => :dep, :allow_nil => false

  def division 
    return Reservation.select{|r| r.route_id == route_id && r.date_trip == date_trip && r.id != id }
  end

  def second
    if (class_point == 2)
      y=division.select{ |l| l.class_point == 2 }.count
      if(y+1 > route.train.II_class_seats)
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end

  def first
    if (class_point == 1)
      y=division.select{ |l| l.class_point == 1 }.count
      if(y+1 > route.train.I_class_seats)
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

I don't understand where the problem is. A friend of mine wrote the same code but it works perfectly to him.

EDIT:

This is the full message error:

```
Started POST "/reservations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-02 15:04:13 +0200
Processing by ReservationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PzfuWIWXqb6C3cCiI+fLendTadwR/kG/++3q6TRcgxLAUGyD1eFluBZB2SZZB3f0ZH6QiRyoj6py+3a6gfOg8A==", "reservation"=>{"class_point"=>"1", "route_id"=>"2", "dep_id"=>"4", "arr_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Create reservation!"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/reservation.rb:12:in `validate'
  app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:32:in `create'


  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.8ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (24.9ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (16.8ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (36.2ms)
```

Comment: Does your friend have _exactly_ the same code? What happens when you run `diff <your_file> <friends_file>`? Does your friend use the same versions of Ruby and Rails? Please post the _full_ error message, including line of code. **Post the error in the question, NOT the comments**

Comment: Also, it looks like you are coming from a javascript, etc background. When you do if statements, you do not need to enclose the statement in parens. They are best used for method arguments OR better defining order of operations.

Comment: ok I posted the full error message

Comment: Might be that your friend tried to create a reservation with parameters that included "date_trip". You are not sending it in your POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Your reservation record that is being validated with DepartureValidator does not have a 'date_trip' attribute (as shown by your logs). Replace `validates_with DepartureValidator` with `validates_with DepartureValidator, if: "date_trip.present?"`

OR

Change your validator to:

```
class DepartureValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if (record.date_trip && record.date_trip < Date.today)
      record.errors[:base]<< ' error '
    end 
  end 
end
```